Is $\left(\frac{R}{\sin\theta}-\frac{R \cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)^2 = \frac{R^2}{\sin^2\theta}(1-\cos\theta)^2$
Is the following true?
$$\left(\frac{R}{\sin\theta}-\frac{R \cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\right)^2 = \frac{R^2}{\sin^2\theta}(1-\cos\theta)^2$$
I don't feel confident that I pulled $R$ and $\sin\theta$ out of the parentheses correctly.

Yes, that is correct.  Let $$x = \frac{R}{\sin \theta}.$$  Then $$\left(\frac{R}{\sin \theta} - \frac{R \cos \theta}{\sin \theta}\right)^2 = (x - x \cos \theta)^2 = (x(1 - \cos \theta))^2 = x^2 (1 - \cos \theta)^2 = \frac{R^2}{\sin^2 \theta}(1 - \cos \theta)^2.$$
